# Listing post type taxonomy in drop down

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have created a custom post type called products and i have categories under it.i have displayed the products list in a page using query post. i need to perform the following now.

- Display a drop down which will list the categories of the post type.

Please assist me.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far